# Duda sobre CMD para el inicio de programas de windows

Tags: cmd

Hace poco se me pidió que realizara un pequeño programa en un archivo por lotes de CMD que permitiera **automatizar el inicio de programas de Windows** de forma que cuando se inicie la computadora, de inmediato se inicien los programas que hay en el archivo `.bat`, **el problema es que aún no entiendo como iniciar el archivo por lotes en cuanto se haya iniciado Windows, ¿como lo hago?.**

Comment: Task scheduler (Programador de tareas creo que es en español)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede realizar desde el programador de tareas:

- El desencadenante debe de ser *Al iniciarse el equipo*:
  [image: Desencadenante de la tarea]
- La *accción*, iniciar un progrma:
  [image: Acción a realizar]
- Y por último, especificar qué programa se va a ejecutar:
  [image: Archivo por lotes a ejecutar]

Espero que te haya sido de utilidad.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puede poner archivos de tipo .cmd en la carpeta Startup.
Tecla de Windows + R, shell:startup (https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps)

Lo que está en esta carpeta se arranca cuando el usario logea.

Ten en cuenta que si el programa tiene que correr como admin, probablemente va a fallecer cuando arrancado automaticamente.